# Is Fortnite: Save the World's global chat really global, or instanced?

Tags: fortnite-save-the-world

Fortnite: Save the World has a *Global* chat room that is available in the pre-game lobby.

I've seen default *General* chat rooms in other games, like Overwatch, but those seemed to be instanced, and your chat instance may be populated with a small number (< 20?) players near you.

However, Fortnite's chat has [just been disabled](https://www.reddit.com/r/FORTnITE/comments/97vbc5/global_and_founders_chat_temporarily_disabled/) due to a combination of spamming, and outright DOSing of player clients through message flooding. This suggests their chat rooms are not so small and isolated.

Is Fortnite's *Global* chat room really global to all players in the game at a given time, or at least all players in the same platform and region?

Comment: I feel like the last 2 questions you ask there would be asking about developer intent, which is not allowed. However, your main question seems to be a valid, and interesting, one.